# Is "offset-fetch and order by" ordering the whole table or partial table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, offset, database-administration

In SQL Server, if I try the following query:

```
select id from table 
order by id
offset 1000000 ROWS
fetch next 1000000 ROWS ONLY;
```

How will SQL Server work? What strategy does SQL server use?

```
1. Do a sorting on the whole table first and then select the 1 million rows we need
2. Do a sorting on partial table and then return the 1 million rows we need.
```

I assume it is 2nd option. If so, how does SQL server decide which range of the table to be sorted?

### Edit 1:

I am asking this question to understand what could cause the query slow. I am testing with two queries:

```
--Query 1:
select id from table 
order by id
offset 1 ROWS
fetch next 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

and

```
--Query 2:
select id from table 
order by id
offset 1000000000 ROWS
fetch next 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I found the second query can take me about 30 minutes to finish while the first takes almost 0 second.

So I am curious on what causes this difference? If the two have same time used for `order by` (or does it even really do a sorting on the whole table? The `id` is the clustered indexed column of the table. I cannot imagine that it takes 0 second to finish sorting on a terabyte table.)

Then if the sorting takes same time, only difference would be the clustered-index scan. For first query, it only needs to scan first 1 or 10 (a small number) of rows. While for the second query, it needs to scan a much bigger number of rows ( >1000000000 ). But I am not quite sure if this is correct.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "partial table"?

Comment: @TabAlleman I use 'partial table' to refer to part of a table. For example, if we only need top 100 rows, sql server may only need to order first 1000 rows of the table to get what we need. But I am not quite sure if this is correct.

Comment: If you think about your question a little bit more, you'll see it makes absolutely no sense.   How can SQL order the "first 1000 rows" without first ordering the entire table to know what the first 1000 rows are?

Comment: @TabAlleman Since the data is organized in B-tree and each intermediate node stores minimum and maximum of the data underneath. Sql server would easily know that sorting on part of the table can satisfy our need. Isn't this right?

Comment: If you are ordering your query on the clustered index, which wasn't originally stated in your question, then you are partially correct.   SQL would know which pages would contain the data, and therefore wouldn't need to look at the entire table at query time, but that's only because the entire table already has been logically ordered by the CI.   You can't skip the step of sorting the entire table, but you can "do it in advance" so to speak, by using the clustered index.

Comment: Thank you Tab for the kind and patient reply. I think my question goes to ``offset``, how does this work in Sql Server? Does Sql server firstly start from left-most leaf and seek to the next leaf until find the page with 1 million(th) row we need? This seems not efficient.

Comment: Since your question is about what happens "under the covers", it is probably more appropriate to ask on dba.stackexchange.com.   Out of curiosity, is there a difference in the execution plans between your first query and second query?   and if there is, what is it?

Comment: There is no difference. the plan is: clustered index scan (clustered) -> TOP -> Select

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a simple example..

```
order by id
offset 50 rows fetch 25 rows only
```

For the above query,the steps would be

1.Table should be sorted by id (if not pay penalty of sort,there is no partial sort,always a full sort)
2.Then scan 50+25 rows(paying cost of 75 rows) and return 25 rows only..

Below is an example of orders table i have(orderid is Pk,so sorted),you can see even though, we are getting only 20 rows ,you are paying cost of 120 rows...

[image]

Coming to your question,there is no partial sort (Which implies first option regarding sort only),even you try to return one row like below..

```
select top 1* from table
order by orderid
```

Comment: Then can I understand that "order by" is not time consuming at all if we are using a clustered index column? The time it takes to run the query only depends on the offset we use? I will add more example in the question description.

Comment: @Lubor:Your edit was aleady answered and you are correct regarding offset